# Why should I use OWIN for a service-based API when I can create web-based RESTful endpoints?

Tags: rest, azure, owin, c#-5.0

I am in the process of rewriting the architecture for an existing application that will be hosted on Azure and have at least two API's - one public, and the other private for internal RESTful-related CRUD calls.

The main technology stack is ODATA, WebAPI2, C#, MVC5, EF, AngularJS.  My thoughts were that the RESTful endpoints would all be exposed through the Azure Web Role (just like any other URL).

In reading more about [OWIN and using it with the WebAPI and the Azure Worker Role](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role), it seems like exactly the same thing, but as a service.

Is there any advantage to going this OWIN route (where come to think of it, I could even write a WCF service to do the same thing) rather than the web-based RESTful API calls?

I'm looking for some reasons why I should go through the exercise of moving to a service-based API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Technology speaking**

For your public API, I would suggest to do it with Owin in a RESTful way. This will create a facade to your internal systems.

Internally, WCF will offer better performances.

---

**PROS**

- Maintenance is way easier with a good plan. Because of its decentralized design, the risks due to refactoring are contained in a specific context. Maintenance is all about minimizing and controlling risks related to changes.

*Those links are more talking about SOA but I'm sure you can extract the information needed from them:*

- [Services by Contracts](http://apievangelist.com/2012/01/12/the-secret-to-amazons-success-internal-apis/)
- [Amazon SOA](http://www.infoq.com/news/Amazon-CTO-Werner-Vogels-on-SOA)
- [Amazon Shareholders Letter](http://www.soabloke.com/category/architecture/soa/)

**CONS**

You should be aware though since it also has drawbacks. You will need solid Unit Test, Logging and Versioning strategies.

---

Hope this helps a little. I tried to keep only the essentials since a complete answer to this question could be published as a book.